# Does Selenium supports Rebellion UI?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate a website built in Rebellion UI. However, even if the button is found, Selenium is not able to click on it. Has anybody faced such issue before or has Any idea about it?

I clicked using usual click and double click both, the color of the button changes but the button is not being clicked by Selenium 2.0 (jar 2.45). Please help.

Comment: I am not sure for Rebellion UI. but you can try injecting java script to click on button as below

// Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance that
// has been properly instantiated elsewhere.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Thanks Dear @Kuldeep!! :)
I already tried with this scripting code.

Comment: Please ignore this question. Rebellion-UI iis a name given by the local developers to their own package. Sorry for any confusion.